# Confusing behaviour of signals and slots depending on type of connection

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have the following snippet

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class Foo : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
        connect(this, &Foo::signal, this, &Foo::slot, ConnectionType);
    }

    void startBlockingMap() {
        qDebug("startBlockingMap");
        slot_counter = 0;
        std::atomic_int signal_counter = 0;
        QtConcurrent::blockingMap(nums, [&](auto &&num) {
            ++signal_counter;
            emit signal();
        });
        qDebug("result: %d signals, %d slots", int(signal_counter), int(slot_counter));
        slot_counter = 0;
    }

public slots:
    void slot() { ++slot_counter; }

signals:
    void signal();

private:
    std::atomic_int slot_counter = 0;
    std::vector<int> nums{1, 2, 5, 8};
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Foo *foo = new Foo(&app);
    QTimer::singleShot(10, foo, [foo, &app]() {
        foo->startBlockingMap();
        app.quit();
    });
    return app.exec();
}
```

It produces different results depending on what connection type is passed to `connect`.

When `ConnectionType` is `Qt::DirectConnection` output is

```
startBlockingMap
result: 4 signals, 4 slots
```

Which is clear.

When `ConnectionType` is `Qt::QueuedConnection` output is

```
startBlockingMap
result: 4 signals, 0 slots
```

Which is not. I thought, slots would be executed after `startBlockingMap` is finished, but they are not executed at all. Why? What happened?

At last, results when `ConnectionType` is `Qt::AutoConnection` are surprising. I expected they would be the same as for `Qt::DirectConnection` or `Qt::QueuedConnection` ([as documentation states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)) but they are different:

```
startBlockingMap
result: 4 signals, x slots
```

Where `x` varies from 0 to 4 depending on… something. Apparently, there is some data race (?). I don't know.

Why are slots not executed with `Qt::QueuedConnection`?
Why output when connection type is `Qt::AutoConnection` differs from output when connection type is direct **and** when it is queued? Why is it so random?

Edit:
With help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982665/7190191), I see that to execute slots connected via queued connection right after `blockingMap`, event loop should be continued explicitly via calling `qApp->processEvents()`.

Comment: Where's your event loop for the main thread? Queued signals are delivered by event loop of the thread. There's no "magic" in how queued signals are delivered, there has to be an actual C++ code which actually calls the method, and that code is part of Qt main loop.

Comment: @hyde I tried to fix it, results are the same

Comment: The issue with your "fix" could be, that the main event loop quits before the threads emit their queued signals. Try adding a separate timer for calling the quit, and give it a bit more time. Also, you don't have to call the `startBlockingMap` from the timer lambda, you can call it before calling the event loop, the signals just won't be delivered until you call `app.exec()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is not. I thought, slots would be executed after maps are finished, but they are not executed at all. Why? What happened?

The slots gets executed when the control get back to the event loop, but here the  `startBlockingMap` function gets called from the event loop, so the slots gets executed when the `startBlockingMap` function returns and the control get back to the event loop.

> Why output when connection type is Qt::AutoConnection differs from output when connection type is direct and when it is queued? Why is it so random?

The blockingMap function use different threads to call your lambda, sometimes a thread from a threadpool, sometimes the thread that executes the blockingMap function(here the 'main' thread). You can check that by adding the line `qDebug() << this->thread() << ' ' << QThread::currentThread();` into the lambda. Now the `emit slot()` gets executed sometimes from a function that is not the owner of the object, so the signal gets queued, sometimes from the 'main'-thread that is the owner of the object, so the slot gets executed directly and you can see the increase in the console.

Comment: So, I would need `qApp->processEvents()` if I want slots to be processed immediately?

Comment: Yes, or you are using a `Qt::DirectConnection`, then the slot gets executed immediately too.